# Generate (query) string from "where" object in waterline.js

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

Using waterline.js in sails.js (0.10.5):

I would like to create a 'where' string out of a where option object. For example, I have:

```
where = {
  updatedAt:{">":"2015-01-08T10:00:00.000Z","<=":"2015-01-08T20:00:00.000Z"}
};
```

and I would like to have a generated string (similar to):

```
"WHERE updatedAt > '2015-01-08T10:00:00.000Z' AND updatedAt <= '2015-01-08T20:00:00.000Z'"
```

Is this possible? I have the feeling it should be...

Comment: It will be very ugly but it's possible to this in js.

Comment: I think he dosen't care doing that in JS, i think he wants to see the "where" condition which is passed to the database engine depending on the adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can do date range queries using the comparison operators.

```
Model.find({ date: { '>': new Date('2/4/2014'), '<': new Date('2/7/2014') } })
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume waterline (or its adapter) must be generating a where-string out of the object. I would like to make use of this where-string inside a `Model.query(..)` rather than executing a `Model.find(..)`.