# Sails.js/waterline: groupBy + count

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

Using sails.js (0.10.5):

I can't figure out how to achieve a groupBy/count using waterline/sails. What I would like to have is something like:

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT('') FROM customer_data GROUP BY customer_id;
or
SELECT customer_id, SUM(1) FROM customer_data GROUP BY customer_id;
```

I wasn't able to achieve this using count nor sum (using a constant):

```
Customer.find({ groupBy:['customer_id'], count: true })
or
Customer.find({ groupBy:['customer_id'], sum: [1] })
```

Both will end in an error, the first "missing calculation" and the second "SQL syntax error".
I can make a grouping using sum with an existing column (`sum: ['id']`) but that does not get me the count.

Am I using the API wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please use `Customer.query('SELECT customer_id, SUM(1) FROM customer_data GROUP BY customer_id', function(err,results){})`

if you don't want use sql, you can like this to use
`Customer.find({groupBy:'customer_id'}).exec`

ref: [waterline-sequel select builder function](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-sequel/blob/master/sequel/select.js#L119)

Comment: Sorry for the late comment: I was thinking about this in combination with a generated where statement (http://stackoverflow.com/q/27852766/3045181). I tried to look at this where-statement-generation, but I found it rather complicated (using waterline-sequel).

Comment: Oh, I see, is unstable module :)

Answer (score 1):

`.query()` is deprecated as of Sails v1.0, instead use `.getDatastore().sendNativeQuery()` (ref: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query). There's still no way to do this with Waterline.